# Emacs font color render problem with Operator Mono

Tags: fonts, emacs

[image]

This problem occurs when I use GNU Emacs 26.1 with Operator Mono font.
Other fonts work fine as far as I have tried.
The problem can happen when Emacs redraws the characters. If I make Emacs redraw (e.g. mark and unmark) those weird characters again, some of them can become normal but some others can become abnormal.

Update: I encountered this problem on Manjora, but Ubuntu works fine, seems Ubuntu does some magic here.